# WYSIWYG-ish AJAX dev tools?

Tags: ajax, wysiwyg, devtools

I'm working with someone who's an experienced system programmer, but is taking on web programming for the first time. What good tools are there to facilitate features like click-to-sort columns in tables, drag-and-drop fields to rearrange ordered values in a table, and other AJAX functionality? I myself am a past Domino developer, and it seems some open source equivalent of the form creation process in Domino would be most useful to him.

Any thoughts? Am I barking up the right tree and are there any useful products on the branches?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Ebase Xi - the latest release, V4.4, has built in AJAX-based screen rendering. Xi is a full RAD platform for wbe development, btw.